# parsing json to object in activity in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a php script returning JSON as shown below:

```
[{"title":"Clothes are selling well","location":"Los Angeles","imageUrl":"xxx","pubDate":"2014-07-26 13:58:08","id":"1"},{"title":"Polo  this summer","location":"UAE","imageUrl":"YYY","pubDate":"2014-07-26 18:05:26","id":"2"},{"title":"Samsung: New tablets","location":"Kuwait","imageUrl":"IIIIII","pubDate":"2014-07-26 18:05:26","id":"3"}]
```

I need to parse this json in my activity class. Any advice on how to do that? I will create an object that has the following attributes:

1. Title
2. Location
3. ImageUrl
4. PubDate

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing JSON is pretty easy in Android. This is how you can parse your current JSON -

```
   //Assuming json holds your JSON as String
   try {
        //Create a JSON array 
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        //Iterate through all the JSON objects
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            //Get ith object
            JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //Get required data from the object
            String title = (String) item.get("title");
            String location = (String) item.get("location");
            String imageUrl = (String) item.get("imageUrl");
            String pubDate = (String) item.get("pubDate");

            //You can now do anything with the data.
            Log.i("TITLE", title);
            Log.i("LOC", location);
            Log.i("IMG_URL", imageUrl);
            Log.i("P_DATE", pubDate);                           

        }                       

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("EXP", "Ooi..! There's an exception.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you are new to parsing JSON there are many easy tutorials for this, like -

- [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)
- [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

[Jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) helps you out to automatically data bind your data to/from JSON.

```
public class Object {
  @JsonProperty
  private  String title;
  @JsonProperty
  private String location;
  @JsonProperty
  private String url;

  @JsonPropery
  private String pubDate;
  @JsonProperty
  private int id;

  //Add set and get method.
}
```

In order to parse the string, you need to use a ObjectMapper object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
Object obj = mapper.readValue(/*your string*/, Object.class);
```

Otherwise, you can easily do by hand using Android [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html).

Answer (score 0):

create Class according to those attributes.
download [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) of Google 
Class Example Name : `Objects`
Example :

```
String json = "....";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Objects obj = (Objects) gson.fromJson(json,Objects.class);
```

Hope it Helps.